ESP32 Flash Encryption with LVGL graphics flickers screen
I have written some code on ESP32s3 N16R8 that uses LVGL as component. My app is working all fine. Then I enabled secure boot security feature and it worked all good, But when I enable flash encryption I observe Flickering on the LCD. what can be issue and how to resolve it.
I set the PSRAM to Octal. PSRAM frequency 80Mhz.
CPU frequency to 240 Mhz.
Flash Frequency to QIO 80Mhz.
But still could not get it fixed.
Porting the same image on another esp32 chip that does not has flash encryption enabled works all fine.

Flash and PSRAM share the same SPI, and while flash reads are memory mapped, write and erase operations are not and PSRAM access is blocked for significant periods during write and especially erase operations.  I suspect that is the cause in this case.
Bit of a gotcha for real-time systems, and an ESP32 design flaw in my opinion.

I have solved the issue by reducing the graphics frequency from LovyanGFX. I have changed cfg.fre_write parameter to 14000000 in LGFX class. earlier it was 16000000
cfg.freq_write = 14000000;

it solved the issue for me.
